# Switch between different versions of a Program (R)

Tags: bashrc, versions, r

I have installed R couple years ago and yesterday I compiled a recent version from source.

I now have version 3.4.4 installed, and it's launched with `R`. Accordingly, I have these command returning like below :

```
~$ R --version
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
~$ which R
/usr/bin/R
```

My newest version is installed in a custom directory like so

```
~/R-3.6.3/bin$ ./R --version
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
~/R-3.6.3/bin$  which R
/usr/bin/R
```

**How can I modify the R version that will be used when I launch `R` ?**

I've tried a modification of the PATH in .bashrc

```
export PATH="$HOME/R-3.6.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME

# result in terminal:
~$ R --version
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
~$ which R
/home/maxime/R-3.6.3/bin/R
# but I don't understand this issue here with sudo
~$ sudo which R
/usr/bin/R
~$ sudo R --version
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
```

It work is some way because when I launch R from terminal, I get the 3.6.3 version. But when I launch R from the desktop, I only get the old version.

Should I modify the R.desktop ? I don't understand because it also send the `R` command...I suppose the .desktop don't get by the .bashrc then...

The ideal solution could be a modification of a line in a file, so I can change this easily and understand which version is used.

Thanks anymay !

Answer (score 2):

You may modify the R.desktop file Exec line to point to `/home/maxime/R-3.6.3/bin/R` instead of just `R`.

Instead of modifying the original R.desktop, you may create a copy under `~/.local/share/applications/` and modify that instead. The make it executable for the system to recognise the file.

Comment: Okay it work when I launch it from desktop (I did this modification for previous soft and understand how it works). But why does it keep using R 3.4.4 when I launch `sudo R`?

Comment: @Gowachin `sudo` is configured to use its own `secure_path` - if you want to run a local version of `R` with `sudo` the easiest way will be to use its full path. Although I don't see why you'd want to run a personal version of R with `sudo` (that sounds like a recipe to mess up the ownership of your files).

Comment: I just want to understand which file is used when I launch R (and Rstudio). The sudo part of the question is more of personnal interest. My principal worries is that however the method I launch R, it's always a chosen version. At this point to set the version I need to modify .bashrc and R.desktop, which I find prone to error if I miss the edition in on file.